# Why does this C program encounter a run-time error?

Tags: c, runtime, malloc

Why do I get a run-time error when it comes to the assignment of `x` and `y` in the following program? How can I rewrite `allocate_node` and `main` to prevent it?

```
typedef struct  
{
  int x;
  int y; 
} Foo;

void allocate_node (Foo * f)  
{ 
 f = (Foo *) malloc ( sizeof(Foo) ); 
} 
 int main ()  
{
   Foo * p;
   allocate_node(p);
   p->x = 2;
   p->y = 3;   
   free(p); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`allocate_node` gets parameter *by value*. Instead, try

```
void allocate_node (Foo ** f)
{
    *f = (Foo *) malloc ( sizeof(Foo) );
}
```

and

```
Foo * p;
allocate_node(&p);
```

---

Or just

```
Foo * p = (Foo *) malloc ( sizeof(Foo) );
p->x = 2;
p->y = 3;   
free(p);
```

Comment: `*f = malloc(sizeof(Foo));`

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have already pointed out the problem and how to fix it. My suggestion is to change the function such that its usage is more natural.

Instead of

```
void allocate_node (Foo ** f);
```

use

```
Foo* allocate_node();
```

Then, you can use:

```
Foo* allocate_node()
{
   return (Foo*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));
}

int main ()  
{
   Foo* p = allocate_node();
   p->x = 2;
   p->y = 3;   
   free(p); 
}
```

I would go further and recommend creating a function to deallocate a `Foo*` to be consistent with the notion that every allocation must have a deallocation, and functions to allocate and deallocate must come in pairs. Also, name the functions `allocate_foo` and `deallocate_foo` to make sure that as your program grows, you have the ability to create other `allocate_xxx` and `deallocate_xxx` functions for other types of objects (Thanks to @gnasher729 for the suggestion).

```
Foo* allocate_foo()
{
   return (Foo*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));
}

void deallocate_foo(Foo* node)
{
   free(node); 
}

int main ()  
{
   Foo* p = allocate_foo();
   p->x = 2;
   p->y = 3;   
   deallocate_foo(p); 
}
```

Comment: I'd call them allocate_foo and deallocate_foo, because once the program gets bigger, you'll want to allocate different things.